# How to count by satisfying different conditions?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to count 'a' (a++) if it satisfies following criteria:

for each cell in range b4 to last used row and column:

1) value of cell in column B should not be equal to "TEXT"

2) value of corresponding cell in column M should not be blank

3) corresponding value of cell in column G should match with elements of following array:

array= {d,e,f,g,h}

Can someone tell me how to do this in VBA?

I tried this code but it doesnt work.

```
For Each elem In arr1
             a = a + WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--WorksheetFunction.IsNA(WorksheetFunction.Match(.Columns(2), "spare", 0))) + WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(13), "<>" & "", .Columns(7), elem))
          Next elem
```

any help/hint is really appreciated.
Thank u so much :)

Comment: What is the output?  What is the input?  what two criteria are you talking about?  What is going on here? Can you add some more details to help people figure out how to help you?

Comment: Is that your real code? What do you mean by "mutually exclusive conditions"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're after this:

```
    For Each elem In arr2
        sweet = sweet _
                + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "active", .Columns(30), "sugar") _
                + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "active", .Columns(31), elem)  
    Next elem
```

Comment: Won't that be adding the count of "active/sugar" for every element in `arr2`, so if there were 5 elements then you would be adding that number 5 times?